# How can I customize a table so that it stacks vertically on media/mobile screens?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

This page: https://eldergod.ca/necronomicodex/ looks great on desktop, but I dislike the horizontal scroll that occurs on some of the longer entries on mobile (I've tried both safari and chrome on my mobile to check).

I've added this CSS to stack all the table columns.  Can I force the table(s) to display at full width of the media device without any horizontal scrolling?

```
/* XL */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    table {width:100%;}
  thead {display: none;}
  tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
  tr td:first-child {background: #070707; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;}
  tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
  tbody td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      display: block;
      text-align:center;}
}

/* Large */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 
   table {width:100%;}
  thead {display: none;}
  tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
  tr td:first-child {background: #070707; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;}
  tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
  tbody td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      display: block;
      text-align:center;}
}

/* Medium */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
     table {width:100%;}
  thead {display: none;}
  tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
  tr td:first-child {background: #070707; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;}
  tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
  tbody td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      display: block;
      text-align:center;}
}

/* Small */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
     table {width:100%;}
  thead {display: none;}
  tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: inherit;}
  tr td:first-child {background: #070707; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;}
  tbody td {display: block;  text-align:center;}
  tbody td:before {
      content: attr(data-th);
      display: block;
      text-align:center;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I can understand you are trying to stack tables vertically for smaller screen sizes. I have achieved this using **media-queries** in CSS.
Here is an example

```css
table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td::before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">XYZ</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Id">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">John</td>
      <td data-label="age">28</td>
      <td data-label="Id">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Alex</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Id">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Dave</td>
      <td data-label="age">20</td>
      <td data-label="Id">4</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps :)